# Omaha poker for loops trough two lists. How to get all possible combinations?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm creating a Omaha (should work for 4 card and 5 card Omaha) poker game in Python. I have two lists. The `playerCardList` is `Card` object list that contains the cards that have been dealt to the player. This list contains 4 or 5 `Card` objects. The `communityCardList` contains the community cards (`Card` objects). This list contains 5 card objects. I have written all functions to check if the player has a royal flush, straight flush etc. These functions need a new `Card` list as parameter. This new list must be a combination of 2 `Card` objects from the playerCardList and 3 `Cards` from the `communityCardList`. I have to check all possible combinations of this. I know this can be done with 2 `for loops`. But I dont really know the right way to do this in a `for loop` so that all possible combinations have been checked. Besides that how do I avoid duplicate checks of `Card` combinations?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample input, desired output, and code for what you've tried so far, so that we can better understand your issue

Answer (score 0):

I would use permutation.

Give all your cards a number and use the permutation library:

```
from itertools import permutations 

# Get all permutations of [1, 2, 3] and print them
perm = permutations([1, 2, 3])       
for i in list(perm): 
    print i
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 1)
```

I hope that is a good start for you to find the solution.
Cheers, keep healthy

Comment: Thank u for your answer! I will research your solution and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations`. It needs a list and it returns another list which are not their duplicates.

```
import itertools

print(*itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 2))
```

Output:

```
(1, 2) (1, 3) (2, 3)
```

If you need some duplicate but shuffeled value you can also use `itertools.permutations`

```
import itertools

print(*itertools.permutations([1,2,3], 2))
```

Output:

```
(1, 2) (1, 3) (2, 1) (2, 3) (3, 1) (3, 2)
```